# Equal Amount of Vertices?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

How would you get the same amount of vertices on 2 different objects in blender cycles? I want to make my mesh text transform into a different word but to do so I need an equal amount of vertices on both different words.

Comment: Could you give a more specific description of how the morphing effect should look like? You see, morphing completely different solid objects without transition effects look quite weird.

Comment: To do a smooth morph of the mesh, I am using shape keys but I am linking those to two separate text objects, but I can't do it without both text objects having the same exact amount of vertices. For example, object 1 needs 120 vertices and object 2 needs 120 vertices.

Comment: I know about the same amount of vertices. What's more important is the effect you want to achieve. There is another way of transforming one text into another that involves particle systems and keyed physics where you don't need to have the same amount of vertices, just the same amount of particles in both objects

Comment: How is that done?

Comment: you could try dissolving the object with an excess of vertices with the decimate modifier until you are close enough to 120 vertices, and then fine tune the number of vertices with remove->dissolve_vertex or remove doubles->merge and increasing the merge distance. I don't know if there is an automated way.

Comment: having an equal amount of vertices wont work as it does not guaranty to have the good corresponding faces

Answer (score 1):

Morphing smoothly between two totally different objects with different vertex counts that also contain submeshes like text or single words is done more easily and efficiently by using particle systems and keyed physics. You basically "fill" your objects (the meshes with its submeshes which in this case are our letters) with particles and then use keyed physics to do the transition.

I recommend the video tutorial from BlenderHQ which you can find here:

[Morphing Particle Systems with keyed Physics in Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPCs4XbGth8)

Answer (score 0):

A **"counter"** answer :

Starting from two texts (and supposing you have triangulate both as the decimate modifier only gives a face count indication... see below), you can tune the decimate modifier so that you obtain the same amount of faces.

- Convert both texts into meshes (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> then *mesh from curve/.../text*)
- Triangulate both (in edit mode, select all the vertices then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
- Add a decimate modifier on the text which has the bigger amount of faces
- Then tune the ratio so that you obtain the same face count as the smaller text

The goal here is to obtain 171 faces :
[image]

- Now apply the modifier
- Select both meshes
- Go to the shape key part (as below) and choose *join as shapes*

[image]

We now have shape keys... but... it does not work...

[image]

Comment: I wonder if a remesh modifier will fix it?

Comment: @AustinH, have a try. But I don't see any mean of how can Blender understand what is expected as final result. There is no information here to tell the faces correspondences. More than that, several faces have to be totally recomposed